# Sockets - sending image

Tags: image, sockets

```
fp = fopen("image.jpg","rb");
if (!fp)
    exit(1);
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_END); 
len = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp,0,SEEK_SET); 
buf = (char *)malloc(len);
fread(buf,len,1,fp);
fclose(fp);


if (WSAStartup(0x0202,&wsa) != 0)
{
    printf("Error code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    return 1;
}



if((s = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0 )) == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    WSACleanup();
    exit(1);
}


server.sin_family = AF_INET;
server.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
server.sin_port = htons( 8888 );


if( bind(s ,(struct sockaddr *)&server , sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("Error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

sprintf(str,"%d",len);
strcpy(message,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: ");
sprintf(message,"%s %s",message,str);
sprintf(message,"%s %s",message,"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n");
sprintf(message,"%s %s",message,buf);
sprintf(message,"%s %s",message,"\r\n");

listen(s , 100);

c = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

while( (new_socket = accept(s , (struct sockaddr *)&client, &c)) != INVALID_SOCKET )
{
    memset(recvdata,'\0',sizeof(recvdata));
    recv(new_socket,recvdata,2000,0);

    send(new_socket , message , strlen(message) , 0);
}

if (new_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
{
    printf("Error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(s);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}
closesocket(s);
WSACleanup();
return 0;
```

}

I have a problem with sending image file. This is server side of communication and browser will be client side. When i try to connect to server, server accepts connection and everything is ok. Then i want to send image as response, and it should be showed in browser. Can anyone tell me what is a problem here?

Comment: What data are received by the client?

Comment: GET / HTTP/1.1

User-Agent: Opera/9.80 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.12

Host: 127.0.0.1:8888

Accept: text/html, application/xml;q=0.9, application/xhtml+xml, image/png, image/webp, image/jpeg, image/gif, image/x-xbitmap, */*;q=0.1

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Connection: Keep-Alive

This is received by client.

Answer (score 2):

Many issues. Just to start:

- You are not checking return values of system calls (`listen()`, `recv()`, `send()`, etc.), so you don't know about errors, and how much data you sent or received.
- Printing binary data like from image file here with `printf()` is a Bad Idea<sup>TM</sup> - it will be truncated at the first zero byte, or it might overrun your memory with a lack of such.
- You are assuming `recv()` consumes full HTTP request from a client. It might not, so you are breaking HTTP protocol.
- You are not closing connected client socket in your loop. That is a resource leak.

Comment: But i just want to send image.I don't care about request.I don't check request by client.This code worked for text.I just changed string message where is request answer and put binary data i read from image file.

Comment: Send binary data directly to the socket, don't "print" it. Your code "worked" with text files by accident. Study HTTP protocol - it's way more complicated then this.

Comment: I wanted to make a string which is response. So i put content type and content length in response. And at the end i wanted to put data.But how to concatenate binary data and rest of response?

Comment: Don't "concatenate", write directly from `buf` to the socket.

Comment: sprintf(str,"%d",len);
strcpy(message,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: ");
sprintf(message,"%s %s",message,str);
sprintf(message,"%s %s",message,"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n");

Comment: send(new_socket ,message , strlen(message) , 0);
send(new_socket ,buf , len , 0);
send(new_socket ,"\r\n" , 5 , 0);

Comment: This combination works now :) But is there a way to convert binary to string?

Comment: You are sending binary data. Why do you need to convert it to string?

Comment: No reason. I was curious how to put whole response with data in 1 string and send it.

Comment: If you really must concatenate the data, just allocate large anough buffer and `memcpy()` one after another.